# regex check for white space in middle of string

Tags: c#, regex, whitespace

I want to validate that the characters are alpha numeric:

```
Regex aNum = Regex("[a-z][A-Z][0-9]");
```

I want to add the option that there might be a white space, so it would be a two word expression:

```
Regex aNum = Regex("[a-z][A-Z][0-9]["\\s]");
```

but couldn't find the correct syntax.

id applicate any incite.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`[A-Za-z0-9\s]{1,}` should work for you. It matches any string which contains alphanumeric or whitespace characters and is at least one char long. If you accept underscores, too you shorten it to `[\w\s]{1,}`.

You should add ^ and $ to verify the whole string matches and not only a part of the string:

`^[A-Za-z0-9\s]{1,}$` or `^[\w\s]{1,}$`.

Answer (score 5):

Exactly two words with single space:

```
Regex aNum = Regex("[a-zA-Z0-9]+[\s][a-zA-Z0-9]+");
```

OR any number of words having any number of spaces:

```
Regex aNum = Regex("[a-zA-Z0-9\s]");
```

Comment: can you tell me how to combine both of them with | please. I have tried and its not working for me

Answer (score 5):

```
"[A-Za-z0-9\s]*"
```

matches alphanumeric characters and whitespace.  If you want a word that can contain whitespace but want to ensure it starts and ends with an alphanumeric character you could try

```
"[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\s]*[A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9]"
```

Answer (score 4):

To not allow empty strings then

```
Regex.IsMatch(s ?? "",@"^[\w\s]+$");
```

and to allow empty strings

```
Regex.IsMatch(s ?? "",@"^[\w\s]*$");
```

I added the ?? "" as IsMatch does not accept null arguments

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check for white space in middle of string you can use these patterns :

1. `"(\w\s)+"` : this must match a word with a white space at least.
2. `"(\w\s)+$"` : this must match a word with a white space at least and must finish with white space.
3. `"[\w\s]+"` : this match for word or white space or the two.