# How to evaluate a RegExp in an array with match groups?

Tags: regex, delphi

I need to parse an array-like text with regular expression and get the match groups.
One example of then text I want to parse is this:

```
['red','green', 'blue']
```

I want to use match groups, because I want to extract them.
I am using this regular expression, but the groups found by it are not like what I expected:

```
\[ *('.+?')( *, *('.+?'))* *\]
```

The idea is to parse in this order:

- A square bracket
- Any number of spaces
- A group with:

  - Single quote
  - Any character
  - Single quote
- Zero or more groups of:

  - Any number of spaces
  - A comma
  - Any number of spaces
  - A group with

    - Single quote
    - Any character
    - Single quote
- Any number of spaces
- A square bracket

And get one group with each parsed array element.

Can you help me?

Hint: a easy way to test regexp is the site http://rubular.com

Comment: You're specifically concerned with Ruby regex, I take it?

Comment: Actually I would use it with Delphi/Pascal, but I was trying to test it with this tool (rubular) that is easier to use.

Comment: "*but the groups found by it are not like what I expected*" What did you expect?

Comment: Okay, please be sure to tag regex questions with the specific language/flavor if you have one in mind.

Comment: Using regex for such trivial parsing case is an overkill.

Comment: @TLama, why do you think this is trivial? How would you do it without regex?

Comment: @Loamhoof I expect to get match groups with an element of the "array" on each

Comment: Which version of Delphi are you using ? Could you add a proper tag, please ?

Comment: @DouglasLise see my comment on Alan's answer (your own comment answered my question in fact :p)

Comment: What if your strings contain [ or ] or , or ' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex: `'([^']+)'`, it should give you the following match groups `red`, `green`, `blue` according to [rubular.com](http://rubular.com/)

Comment: It's right. I tried to parse the entire string using groups and I couldn't figure out that this could be done with multiple matches. I would wait some hours if somebody else answer according to the question (using groups), else I would accept your answer. Thank you a lot.

Comment: @DouglasLise don't bother, you can't match an arbitrary number of groups with one regex.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't going to be a totalitarian answer, but I'm fairly certain you can't whitespace check by doing " *", at least it may depend on the language you're using.

Here's a C# regex example that shows some of the language requirements to check for whitespace: [regex check for white space in middle of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531079/regex-check-for-white-space-in-middle-of-string)

Edit: I see you added Ruby as your language, unfortunately I'm not verbose in Ruby so specifics I cannot help you with, sorry.

Edit2: Seeing as you're forcing yourself into Ruby to debug your regex statement, might I suggest: http://www.debuggex.com/ which tries to stay language independent?

Comment: OK, but I've tried without considering spaces and it still not working. But thank you by the answer.

Comment: Nice tool (debuggex.com). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**You can** match an arbitrary number of groups with one regex:

```
^\[\s*|(?:\G'([^']+)'\s*(?:,\s*|]$))+
```

or like this (should be more performant):

```
^\[\s*+|(?>\G'([^']++)'\s*+(?>,\s*+|]$))++
```

This work in ruby like asked before, in delphi I don't know.