# How to find white spaces in a String using regex?

Tags: java, android, string

I have an EditText for password field in my registration form. I want to show error if user enters a whitespaces in password field. So please give RegEx or any other solution to find any spaces in string?
Thanks

Comment: Does this help you? I'm sorry, but you could have googled that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531079/regex-check-for-white-space-in-middle-of-string

Comment: Better to add your code snippet. But it looks very basic validation check. Google search can tell you easily

Comment: Can't you use Google? Too lazy for searching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use as

```
variable.contains(" ")
```

Or with regex as

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
boolean found = matcher.find();
```

Comment: awesome! I used variable.contains(""). its working fine for me.