# How to remove only LineFeed from a line in C#

Tags: c#

I have an input file from a database download that randomly has lines that (when viewed in NotePad++) have a LineFeed, but not a carriage return indicator.

For example:

```
Code|Description
123|Information Given
456|More Information Given
789|Even More
Informtion Given
012|Some Other Information

The 789 line, in the file, has an LF but not a CRLF.
I've tried code like
  if (line.Contains((char)13))
or
  if (line.Contains("\r")
or
  if (line.Contains('\r")
```

but when stepping through it in the debugger, no line shows as having the line feed. I'm using a StreamReader of the text file to read through the file line-by-line, and that's how the line variable is filled. Can a "string line" not contain those characters?

This file is thousands of lines long and used in an automated process that uses it as an input. Due to this, the fixing of the file is needed before the next process step runs and encounters malformed lines.

Comment: I have no idea what `line` is here or how it was populated. Don't you think showing the related code would be helpful.

Comment: StreamReader already knows how to deal with this problem.  And removes the line-ending when you use ReadLine() so your Contains() will never be true.  So there is no point in trying to fix this problem :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [regex check for white space in middle of string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531079/regex-check-for-white-space-in-middle-of-string)

Comment: @JonathanWood Line is a string and the lines in the file are shown above as the example of what is read into "line."

Comment: @JonathanWood - It's pretty clear from the question what the variable `line` is.

Comment: @AndrewCooper: It's likely a string but could be an array. Neither the variable declaration or how it's being populated was shown. Are you against showing the lines of code that fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the StreamReader strips off the line termination characters ('\r' and '\n') when you're reading line-by-line.

One solution is to read the whole file and then use something like `.Split('\r').Trim()` to split into lines around the CR character.

If you need to read line-by-line you could check each line for a code element at the front, and where it doesn't exist appending the string to the previous line.

Comment: Based on your suggestion of "If you need to read line-by-line you could check each line for a code element at the front, and where it doesn't exist appending the string to the previous line.", I set the code to look for the "|" symbol as an indication that the line was the beginning of the correct statement then appended each like after it until a line had a "|" in it, signifying I had a new statement. That resolved the issue for me. The note that StreamReader strips off the characters clarified the confusion. Thank you, @Andrew.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the line starts with three digits and a pipe symbol. If it does not then it is a continuation of the previous line.